# How avoid PHP error message when using XML declaration in an SVG file?

Tags: php, svg, visual-studio-code

I am using PHP inside an SVG file, to adjust colours and whatnot, with PHP variables. The file is saved with a `.php` extension.

The problem is, the first line of an SVG file is wrongly interpreted by VS Code, it keeps complaining that I have to add`;` characters in this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Error in line 1:

```
';' expected at 1,6  
';' expected at 1,10
';' expected at 1,37
```

How can I tell VS Code to allow SVG XML declarations?

Comment: Are you creating the file using an API or by concatenating strings?

Answer (score 2):

You don't: that error is 100% correct. If this is a PHP file, you're going to need to explicitly echo that XML declaration, as `<?` is a shorthand code for entering PHP mode.

You really do need to change your code in this case, e.g.:

```php
<?php
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>';
?>

<svg version="..." xmlns="..." ...>

<!-- normal SVG code here -->

<?php

  // intermixed with more php code

?>

...

</svg>
```

Comment: PHP short tag can be disabled (and is even deprecated).

Comment: ...and....? Deprecated simply means "it works for now, until we remove it in a future version", so right now, this is 100% a real error and the proper way to deal with it is to `echo` the offending line, as we've been doing for literally decades now.